# Custom ListView in Fragment not adhering to parent theme

Tags: android, android-listview, android-theme

I'm currently having an issue with using custom ListView adapters with the Holo.Light theme. Within the activities and fragments, any TextViews are displayed in the theme's normal colours (`textColorPrimary`). However, any text within the custom ListAdapter uses `textColorPrimary` from the default Holo theme, effectively making the text unreadable.

Here is an example from my app's main menu:

---

**list_main_menu.xml** - The row layout for the ListAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:textSize="12pt"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSecondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtFirstLine"
        android:text="Line 2"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Note:* I'm currently having to use `android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"` to make the text readable.

---

**fragment_main_menu.xml** - The Main Menu fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtWelcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />     
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**AndroidManifext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.michaeldodd.treasurehunter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".gui.Login" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".gui.Home" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
        <activity android:name=".gui.UserProfile" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
        <activity android:name=".gui.MapList" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" /> 
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

I'm not currently using any custom styles. Thanks for reading, and any useful comments will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Here's the requested screenshots.
[image: asdf]
This is how it looks if I don't specify the text colour, it seems to be using the default text colour for Holo Dark

[image: asdf]
Manually specifying `android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"` gives this result, but I'm uneasy at using a workaround like this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You haven't posted any actual code, but since I've had exactly the same problem, I would guess that you are passing the wrong `Context` to your custom adapter constructor.

I've been doing something like this (within my Fragment):

```
dataSource = new MyCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.myrow, data,
            fields, new int[] { R.id.field1, R.id.field2 });
```

All I had to do to fix the problem, was to replace `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` by `getActivity()`:

```
dataSource = new MyCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.myrow, data,
            fields, new int[] { R.id.field1, R.id.field2 });
```

And it started to work as expected.

MyCursorAdapter (extending `SimpleCursorAdapter`) constructor:

```
public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) { //... }
```

Comment: Finally! I looked days for this! Thank you very much!

Comment: You saved me..!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same problem and reading what rockford posted I could solve it, don't be necessary to use getApplicationContext() when you're implementing an adapter.

Here is the code of my ListFragment class:

```
public class TipoProveedorFavoritoActivity extends ListFragment {

    Context mContext;
    MiApp myApp;
    Usuario usuario;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getActivity();
        myApp = (MiApp)getActivity().getApplication();
        usuario = myApp.usuario;

        // Progress Dialog

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);


        Log.d("usuario", String.valueOf(usuario.id));

        ConsultaDB consulta = new ConsultaDB();
        consulta.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tipoproveedorfavorito_activity, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

    // Creamos la clase para el adaptador de los tipos de proveedores
    public static class TipoProveedorArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TipoProveedor>
    {
        public Context context;
        public List<TipoProveedor> listaTipoProveedor;

        public TipoProveedorArrayAdapter(Context context,List<TipoProveedor> listaTipoProveedor){
            super(context, R.layout.tipoproveedorfavorito_activity,listaTipoProveedor);

            this.context = context;
            this.listaTipoProveedor = listaTipoProveedor;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View view;
            if(convertView==null){

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =  (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tipoproveedor_content, parent,false);                
                final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

                //holder.txtId=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtId);
                holder.txtTipoProveedor=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTipoProveedor);

                view.setTag(holder);
                holder.txtTipoProveedor.setTag(listaTipoProveedor.get(position));
            }else{
                view=convertView;
                ViewHolder holder2 = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
                holder2.txtTipoProveedor.setTag(listaTipoProveedor.get(position));
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            TipoProveedor tipoProveedor = listaTipoProveedor.get(position);
            //holder.txtId.setText(String.valueOf(tipoProveedor.id) );
            holder.txtTipoProveedor.setText(tipoProveedor.tipoProveedor);

            return view;

        }

        private class ViewHolder{
            //public TextView txtId;
            public TextView txtTipoProveedor;

        }

    }

    private class ConsultaDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, TipoProveedorArrayAdapter>{

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(TipoProveedorArrayAdapter result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            setListAdapter(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected TipoProveedorArrayAdapter doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String SQL = "SELECT t2.tipoProveedor AS id,t3.descripcion From Favoritos t1 " +
                    "INNER JOIN Proveedor t2 ON t2.id = t1.idProveedor " +
                    "INNER JOIN TipoProveedor t3 ON t3.id = t2.tipoProveedor " +
                    "Where t1.idUsuario = ? GROUP BY t2.tipoProveedor,t3.descripcion ORDER BY t2.tipoProveedor";

            UtilDB db = UtilDB.GetUtilDb(mContext);
            db.openDataBase();

            Cursor cursor = db.getDataBase().rawQuery(SQL,new String[]{String.valueOf(usuario.id)});
            //Cursor cursor = db.getDataBase().rawQuery(SQL,null);

            List<TipoProveedor> tipoProveedor = new ArrayList<TipoProveedor>();

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                String descripcion = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("descripcion")); 

                TipoProveedor tp = new TipoProveedor();
                tp.id=id;
                tp.tipoProveedor=descripcion;
                tipoProveedor.add(tp);

            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            TipoProveedorArrayAdapter adapter = new TipoProveedorArrayAdapter(mContext, tipoProveedor);
            //setListAdapter(adapter);

            return adapter;
        }

    }

}
```