# Applying custom theme to ActionBar in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-preferences

I am trying to apply custom theme to `ActionBar` in `PreferenceFragment`. Following is the scenerio:

My class extends `PreferenceFragment` in which I am adding preferences from resouces as:

```
addPreferenceFromResource (R.xml.myPrefs);
```

Also, I have written:

```
ActionBar a = getActivity ().getActionBar ();
bar.setNavigationMode (ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

Now I want to apply my own theme that I defined in `styles.xml` to this action bar. Currently, the height of action bar is smaller that the tab view due to which the view is getting cropped.

I tried searching but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

1. "[Set theme for a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment)"
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/GX_gOAN2nmM

From 1. and 2. links above, I learnt that:

```
final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),R.style.yourCustomTheme);

// clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

// inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
```

But this also didn't work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found solutions to my problem. Seems like there was a simple solution while I tangled myself into complex things.

I just added the following line to the `onCreate ()` of my `PreferenceFragment` class... and everything became perfect!

```
getActivity ().setTheme (R.style.myCustomTheme);
```

Hope it helps someone who might face the same problem!  :)

Comment: Doesn't this override the theme for the entire activity?  It does for me.  IE when I change fragments the theme is different, and I would have to change it back again.