# How to change a PreferenceFragment style/theme?

Tags: android, styles, fragment, themes, preference

I have a PreferenceFragment and I want to change the background, text color, and a couple other things however I can't find a way to change the fragments style without affecting other fragments in my app.

I tried a solution mentioned at [Applying custom theme to ActionBar in PreferenceFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825013/applying-custom-theme-to-actionbar-in-preferencefragment)
which said to put `getActivity ().setTheme (R.style.myCustomTheme);` in onCreate however that affects all of my other fragments since they are using the same activity as the PreferenceFragment.

Is there a way to change **only** the PrefrenceFragment style without affecting the activity/other fragments?

Thanks!

EDIT: I guess I could make it a seperate activity and change the theme that way but I would really like to keep it a fragment if possible.

Comment: Also looking for a solution for this...