# Android use colorControl for single EditText

Tags: android, android-activity, colors, android-edittext, styles

I want to use the android colorControlNormal/Activated/Highlight style property for a single EditText, not for the entire activity. Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override theme attributes like `android:colorControlNormal` for a particular view or hierarchy of views using the `android:theme` attribute. This attribute is supported on devices running API 21+.

First, define an overlay theme. This is a theme with no parent that defines only the attributes you want to override.

res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="MyThemeOverlay">
   <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/myControlColor</item>
</style>
```

Then set the theme on your view or view group.

res/layout/my_layout.xml

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly :) But will it work on Kitkat when using AppCompat?

Comment: Maybe! I think we support the `app:theme` attribute on a number of classes when using appcompat-v7, but I am not certain of the specifics. For general-purpose use, you can always apply the theme overlay at run-time by using a `ContextThemeWrapper` and obtaining a layout inflater from the wrapped context.

Comment: So I just tried it and the property is in fact not working on kitkat. Could you point me into any direction using ContextThemeWrapper?

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment), which shows how to create a theme wrapper and obtain a `LayoutInflater` for it.

Comment: @Broadwell did you make it work on api level < 21 ? I tried the contextThemeWrapper but that did not work.