# How to Start File Picker Intent In Dialog Instead Of Activity

Tags: android

in order to keep my Application more stable and faster, and since i have alot of file picking actions in my application , i prefer to pick the files in a dialog instead of an activity , so the activity in background will not pause and restart.. currently this is the method that i am using :

```
    Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // The MIME data type filter
    target .setType("*/*");
    // Only return URIs that can be opened with ContentResolver
    target .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
            target, getString(R.string.expandable_title));
```

my question is how can i set theme of the opened activity to dialog guys? thanks alot

Comment: Your dialog is a fragment. You can override `onCreateView` method like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment)

Comment: Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT , opens an activity that you dont have access to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my question is how can i set theme of the opened activity to dialog guys?

You can't. It is not your activity. You are welcome to write your own file-chooser dialog if you wish, but you cannot force other activities, from other apps, to adopt certain themes.

Comment: thats what i was hopping be not true, thanks any way