# Android setTheme() not changing ActionBar and Status Bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-theme, android-styles

I have an `ActionBarActivity` which has fragments for a navigation drawer. When an item in the navigation drawer is pressed, it starts the corresponding fragment.
In each of these fragments, the `onCreate()` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

The theme that is applied is different for each of these fragments however.

I noticed that the `setTheme()` method does not appear to change the colour of the `ActionBar` or status bar as declared in the `styles.xml` from which I am referencing:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand_red_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_red_primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Again, there are different styles with different `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` attributes for the different fragments in my activity.

So, the `setTheme()` method does not change the colour of the `ActionBar` or status bar, but it does change some things like the colour of the pullback feature in a listview, for example.

Am I missing something, or is there something I need to do for `setTheme()` to change the `ActionBar` and status bar colour?

### UPDATE:

I tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/4230345) but it gives me exactly the same result as what I had tried before (using `setTheme()`).

Comment: Check this, for changing theme from Fragment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/3736955

Comment: Are you trying to implement material theme in your app ?

Comment: @Radix Yes, I'm trying to implement material themes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the following method to solve my issue:

```
private void updateActionBar(int title, int actionBarColor, int statusBarColor) {
    if (title != 0) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(title));
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
    }


    if (actionBarColor != 0) {
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(actionBarColor)));
    }


    if (statusBarColor != 0) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(statusBarColor));
        }
    }

}
```

I have been calling this method before changing the `Fragment`, but have also kept using `getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);` or `getActivity().setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_colourTwo);` in the `onCreate` method of the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call setTheme(..) before super.onCreate(..),and It works for me:

```
setTheme(R.style.YourThemeName);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change background color , text color of the action bar via defining a custom style.

Edit your **styles.xml** file in your project

```
<resources>
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar title text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>

<!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabText"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
</resources>
```

and then use the setTheme() to set the **CustomActionBarTheme**

for more info [check here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Also if you are trying to implement material theme, do the below and it applies to the places as mentioned in the image you commented with

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

where my application uses the **AppTheme** (..usually specified in the manifest..as below )

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    ..
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: That could work, but I thought that the `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` attributes would change the ActionBar as shown in the [diagram from the developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/material/images/ThemeColors.png). Also, I don't think this would change the status bar colour.