# Android: Unable to set getContext() in non-static method - requires API Level 23

Tags: android-studio, android-api-levels

Below, is some source code which is being called from a non-static method.  I'm getting the error

> "Call requires API level 23 (current min is 15);
>   android.app.Fragment#getContext"

```
android.content.Context context = (Context) getContext();
```

How can I get the context object?

Under the object explorer > Gradle Scripts > build.gradle, I see this.  Looks like version 23 to me.  Am I looking in the correct location?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

Looks like I have Android Studio 1.5.1.  I just chose the SettingsActivity project template in Android Studio.  And added one class to that default code.

Comment: What happens if you call `getActivity` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to import import android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of import android.support.app.Fragment;

Answer (score 5):

Pass  `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()` as  Context.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve was to cast "this" (activity) to (Context) inside the Activity onCreate method.