# Android - Theme not applying to a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, themes

I've been making an app with a given theme. All was running the best but I find out that my Fragments were themeless. Seems that the app theme isn't applying to my fragments and it's frustrating me. Did I forget a step? Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to use contextThemeWrapper and make sure your manifest file themes are in place.

[It was already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment)