# Fragments with different themes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-theme

I'm having a bad struggle in trying to change the theme of my Android Activity in runtime.

This is what I'm trying to archieve:
I have an activity (MainActivity) which contains three fragments. Two of those fragments should have a toolbar and a normal status bar, but the third one shouldn't have a toolbar and should have a transparent status bar with content behind it. So, I created two styles: the normal AppTheme with toolbar etc and another one called Fullscreen without those. Now, the theme should change when the fragments are being switched.

I have tried to just change the theme after inflating a new fragment, but that didn't work (obviously).

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment) and a few others and they almost all contain the same answer which doesn't work for me.

I really hope one of you could help!

Thanks

Comment: That should not be a problem to use different themes for different fragment instances. Including some of your code would help us better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can modify `Activity` theme and then `recreate` it to see its effect

```
class YourActivity{
boolean isThirdFragmentVisible;
...
public void onNavigateToThirdFragment(){
   setTheme(<full screen theme>);
   isThirdFragmentVisible = true;
   recreate();
}

...
public void onCreate(){
   if(isThirdFragmentVisible){
       showThirdFragment();
   }
}
...
}
```

Comment: obviously `isThirdFragmentVisible` in `onCreate` will be always false ...

Answer (score 0):

Any fragment has access to the attached activity. So, fragments can set any activity property, like toolbar and status bar.

Example:

**Status bar:**

- In onViewCreated callback you can set this mode to not show the status bar:

  ```
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
  ```
- To show the status bar in the other fragments, you can set it in the same way:

  ```
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
  ```

**Toolbar:**

In the same way, the toolbar can be set by any fragment using `setSupportActionBar` activity method. More information >
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar