# Replacing activity theme in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, themes

I'm trying to set a theme for a fragment within an activity.

When I set the fragment theme in the onCreate function of the fragment using the inflator as described in [Set a theme for a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment) like this:

```
    var contextThemeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.FragmentTheme);
    var localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper)
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_component_indicator, container, false)
```

or in the layout of the fragment XML, the theme for the fragment does not take effect.

Using the Layout Inspector, I see that the theme does get added to the fragment layout but the activity theme is still there:

[image]

Any tips on how I can set the theme of the fragment?

Thank you.

Comment: did you try to add this code in onCreateView ?

Comment: yes, i tried it in the onCrreateView of the fragment.

Comment: So they are both applied. This is how I'd expect it to work. Now you fragment theme should just override the styles and everything should work as expected. Correct me if I'm wrong. Also it be nice to know why you want to do this as we might be able to suggest an alternative approach...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override context theme in `Fragment.onGetLayoutInflater()` method. This is place where fragment view is not inflated yet.

```
override fun onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): LayoutInflater {
    context?.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppName_Light)
    return super.onGetLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState)
}
```