# Is there any way to change fragment theme?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, styles, android-architecture-navigation

I'm currently using 'Navigation component' in my project, using 'Single Activity' approach.
Each of my fragments has transparent status bar and different windowBackground.
I'm looking for a way to change fragments windowBackground, without affecting the other fragments.

I've tried the solution mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/11402079
But it didn't work.
I can't find anything related to this 'Single Activity' approach.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use ContextThemeWrapper to provide the different theme to fragment.While appplying contextThemeWrapper , your minSDKVersion should be >=11 .

Use this in the onCreateView method of fragment

```
final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme);
```

Comment: That won't affect window flags like those used for the transparent status bar or window background. You'd also have more luck just adding a `android:theme` to the root of the Fragment's layout if you're trying to achieve this approach for views within the Fragment