# setTheme from fragment

Tags: android, android-theme

I would like to change a theme of my app.
It works when I'm calling in my Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.PaywallTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

However, my architecture requires to call it from Fragment and it doesn't work, because `setTheme` should be called before Activity's `onCreate`. Any how to solve it?

Comment: Try from onActivityCreated

Comment: It should be called before Acitivity's `super.onCreate` that's the problem :(

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469174/set-theme-for-a-fragment) might help

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. In the end, I'm coloring my toolbar programmatically.