# Hiding AppBarLayout upon viewing a certain Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-designer

i am new to android and trying to implement a main activity with tabs, each tab contains a fragment, and upon one of the fragments i would like the whole app bar to disappear (its intended to be a camera fragment) , leaving the certain fragment in FullScreen mode, this is what i have so far:

file : **MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       //this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);


        final AppBarLayout bar = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout2); // the app bar layout that i want gone

        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab)
            {
                onTabSelected(tab);
            }
        });
```

as you can see, i am trying to implement a tabs listener along with a ViewPager, i have tried implementing inside an if statement on the bar.position():

- ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide(); - app crashes
- getActionBar().hide() - returns null and also crashes
- getWindow().setFlags(
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); - doesnt work

file : **main_activity.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".UIActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_pager">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/logo1" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp" /><!-- #86B2E8 -->
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view_pager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the cameraFragment.java and xml files are a standard files, i still do not know how i can hide the app bar when a user clicks on the camera tab, and return it once he swipes back to an another Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

the action bar belongs to the activity, not your fragment. but you can create a style with no action bar and change the style on the beginning of the fragment.

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496425/8244139 , you should use the code below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme);

    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

    // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: does this code change the style of the MainActivity or the fragment?, i've tried using the FullScreenTheme and my Camera Fragment layout in the inflater, it didn't apply any change

Comment: as I said, activity is the one holding the action bar. if you want to remove the action bar, you have to change the activity's theme when opening a fragment.