# Mixed Themes in Android Layout

Tags: android, android-activity, themes, android-viewpager

Well. I have an Activity that contains a ViewPager with three pages.

The activity is using the light theme. I have set it in the manifest

> ```
>           <!-- PANTALLA PEDIDO-->
>               <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait"
>                     android:name="com.adelco.carro.Pedido"
>                     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
>                     <intent-filter>
>                       <action android:name="com.adelco.carro.Pedido" />
>                       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
>                     </intent-filter>
>           </activity>
> ```

The first two pages look correct... This is a screenshoot of the 1st page:

[image: Page 1]

and this is is the screenshoot of the 3rd page:

[image: page 3]

wtf! Why the TextViews are taking the Black theme color? A ViewPager's page is a fragment and should inherit the theme of the parent activity...

What should I do? I don't want to force the text color.....

P.S: I have another ViewPager in other Activity and the colors are ok... This is so weird

A little more of code:
Activity Layout (The useful code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                            android:id="@+id/pager_informacion"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:text="Artículos"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textSize="28sp"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
        </TextView>
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="0dip"
                     android:layout_weight="1" >
                <ListView android:id="@+id/lista_articulos"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                          android:divider="@color/negro">
                </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Adapter layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:scaleType="fitXY"
               android:id="@+id/iv_tipo_producto">
    </ImageView>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_descripcion" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                  android:paddingRight="5dp">
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see the code is very simple... I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Seems like the textColor attribute of the TextView on the layout is overwriten. Maybe you have apply styles and change the color? Please add the code of the XML layout.

Comment: I don't think so... I'm not using any kind of color attributes... The colors of the Layouts are the "default" colors of the theme...

Comment: Try to add in the adapter layout the property textColor="@color/negro" to the TextView.

Comment: Well... That is the "easy and simple" solution... But if in the future I want to change the theme then this part will look ugly, because all the app (except this page of this fragment) is following  the color scheme of the theme...

Comment: So doing this shows the right color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the way that calls the method to fill the listView. Is very probably that the context passed to the app isn't correct and don't retain the app  theme.

Try to pass the Activity context instead call getAplicacionContext().

Like this:

```
dataSource = new MyCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.myrow, data,
        fields, new int[] { R.id.field1, R.id.field2 });
```

More info: [Custom ListView in Fragment not adhering to parent theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994033/custom-listview-in-fragment-not-adhering-to-parent-theme)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes!.... I was using "getActivity().getApplicationContext()" and I changed it for "getActivity()".... And now works!!! Thank you.