# Incorrect theme applied to some parts of App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-theme

Previously, the Holo Light theme was applied throughout my entire App. That is however no longer the case it may seem.

Although the Action Bar, background and whatnot are correct, other parts are not. Specifically, the default text color is now very light grey, almost white, as well as some CheckBoxes appears to be using an older theme.

The following images demonstrates the checkbox issue (don't mind the icon to the left or the background color):

[[Expectation]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHLrf.png), [[Result]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNNfF.png)

I haven't had this issue in the 2 months before today, that I've been developing this App, so I am guessing I must have done something to cause this weird behaviour. I've tried retracing my steps, but with no success.

The views containing these checkboxes are displayed in a ListView, but when I display checkboxes other places in the App, outside of this ListView, they appear as expected.

I would like to point out that the checkbox is not the only issue, the default text color also got messed up, *everywhere* in the App.

My test device is a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini running Android 4.1.2.

**build.gradle**

```
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 17
    }
    ...
```

**res/layout/___.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cd_icon" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
            android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/active"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
...
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

---

### Solution

I narrowed down the issue to only ListViews and did some more searching on that. It turns out that I was using the wrong context in my list adapters. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212533/3252091) was quite simple: Use the activity context instead of the application context in adapters.

**Before**

```
public DelegatedAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}
```

**After** - [Custom ListView in Fragment not adhering to parent theme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212533/3252091)

```
public DelegatedAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}
```

Comment: What did you change between the time you had the right behavior and now? Do you have a `styles.xml` file in values-11 or values-14 folders (those take over for devices with api levels 11, 14 and up)?

Comment: I posted the solution, but to answer your question: No, I didn't have any additional `styles.xml` files.